# Feature Selection: Having a large number of features select those features that classify the target class best

Tags: feature-selection

I have time series data and I'm using the [cesium package](http://cesium-ml.org/) to extract several [features](http://cesium-ml.org/docs/feature_table.html).

Now the thing is, the number of extracted features is pretty significant. I have tried various visualizations to make sense of what features classify my labels the best but it is too cumbersome for so many features.

Are there any algorithms or packages available that I can use for feature selection?

Comment: Have you tried PCA or TSNE? these are nothing but dimensionality reduction techniques, so my question boils down to have you tried any Dimensionality Reduction Technique?

Comment: @Kaustubh I'm trying to implement various approaches mentioned [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_selection.html)

Comment: Ok, Do you have a strategy/rationale for using or not using any of the algorithms mentioned on that page?